# How to remove the arrays given in the arrows

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

```
$session_activity_category = array();

    foreach($search_venue as $venue_b)  {
    $session_activity_category[] =  $this->users_model->search_categories_by_session($venue_b->activity_venue_id);
}


 return $this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_status_header(200)
    ->set_output(json_encode(array('activity_category'=>$session_activity_category,'activity'=>$session_activity,'activity_session'=>$search_session,'activity_venue'=>$search_venue),JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)  
    );
```

I want to remove the arrays given in the arrow lines

[image: These arrows which are given in which I want to remove the arrays]

Comment: Do you want to remove only the first element?

Comment: _remove arrays given in the arrows_? what is that even mean? please elaborate, you mean its giving you unneeded array dimensions? or maybe you just meant merging them, inside of adding (or pushing) new batches every iteration

Comment: Please don't add JSON (or code) as images

Answer (score 2):

Convert the JSON to the array. Then just create a new array with the same key active category (in my example, something):

```
<?php

$json = '
{"something": [[
        {
            "blah": "blah"
        },
        {
            "blah": "blah"
        }
    ]]}
';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

$array = [
    "something" => $array['something'][0],
];

echo json_encode($array);
```

Which will output:

```
{"something":[{"blah":"blah"},{"blah":"blah"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `$this->users_model->search_categories_by_session($venue_b->activity_venue_id)` returns array of objects. You should parse this objects to the $session_activity_category array each iteration of search_categories_by_session function call.

```
    $session_activity_category = array();

    array_walk($search_venue, function($venue_b) use (&$session_activity_category) {
        $categories = $this->users_model->search_categories_by_session($venue_b->activity_venue_id);

        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            $session_activity_category[] = $category;
        }
    });
```